# BASE64 encoding in apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am wondering if there's a way I can do base64 encoding in pig latin scripts. For example, in hive, there's a function called base64() where I can simply pass in a variable. I would like to do something like:

```
items = LOAD 'somepath' using AvroStorage()
items = Filter items by base64(somefield)=="somestring"
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: No.Please write your own udf in Python or Java.Its a one line code in Python or Java.